# How to make a Product page without ordering and database

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, database

I am learning Wordpress currently so far I know how to design the webpage, but what I want to do next is to make a product page without ordering. What I want is the following:

1. List all my products and if one clicks on a product it will show the detail page of that product
2. The products can be added to a list and then there will be a contact form which will take the list and send it to me in a pdf or excel (but at first enough if only names are sent via email) so I can answer it with the asked question.

I sadly could not find any starting point I do not even know if there is such a plugin, if not can I make one myself? I know javascript so I think I could Programm it myself but would prefer if there is some plugin I can use due to time issues.

Comment: What you are asking is beyond the scope of WPSE discussions and kind of - Do It For Me - to some extent. If you need to list your products, you will have to make a query to database because its where they are saved. A good starting point would be learning how [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) works.

Comment: No I really just do not know where to start, I am ready to develop a plugin for this as well if needed. I just need a few pointers to start my way, like how to bind and how to start etc